# Qt Creator incorrect indentation after åäö

Tags: c++, qt-creator, indentation

I have been using *Qt Creator* and C++ for many years, but recently the *auto indentation* has begun to fail if the previous line contains a *Swedish character*, e.g. å.

Below is an example. I have selected all text and pressed ^I. As a result line 8 is indented incorrectly (even though the letter å is within a string!!).  It works fine if I remove the character å.  (I am using Utf-8).

Q: Can anyone explain this behaviour and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: I am using Qt Creator 11.0.2

Comment: This doesn't seem intentional behavior. I recommend you make a bug report to the Qt Creator team.

Comment: The issue was resolved in Qt Creator 12.0.1